# Check value in rows

Tags: sql

I have the table below

```
ID  | PARCEL  | STATUS  | ORDER_ID
1     1         PENDING      1234
2     2         COMPLETE     1234
3     1         COMPLETE     9999 
4     2         PENDING      9999   
5     3         PENDING      9999
6     1         COMPLETE     1111
7     2         COMPLETE     1111
8     3         COMPLETE     1111   
9     1         COMPLETE     3333 
10    2         PENDING      3333
```

i need get results when the first parcel is PENDING and have more than one parcel.

i try with the sql:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE parcela = 1 AND status = 'pending'
group by order_id
having count(order_id) > 1
```

the answer for the query is:

```
ID  | PARCEL  | STATUS  | ORDER_ID
1     1         PENDING      1234
2     2         COMPLETE     1234
```

Comment: And what is your expectation?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Also, what database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the orders using a `having` clause:

```
select order_id
from table 
group by order_id
having count(order_id) > 1 AND
       sum(case when parcela = 1 AND status = 'pending' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

If you want the details, join the rows from the table back in on the `order_id`.

The problem with your query is that you are using a filter in the `where` clause that limits the rows to only the first row.  This prevents the query from counting the total number of rows in each order.

Comment: That query dont get the expected result. I want all rows when the order_id have > 1 parcel and the first parcel is pending

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade . . . This should return all orders that have those conditions.  How are the results unexpected?

Comment: i want show all parcels with result. like
ID  | PARCEL  | STATUS  | ORDER_ID
1     1         PENDING      1234
2     2         COMPLETE     1234